# sharepoint 2010 exceptionally slow for first load

Tags: performance, sharepoint

Iam have a load balanced windows authenticated sharepoint 2010 farm.

I also have a similar setup on another farm.

Now the issue is that on the first load page load performance issue. In fact both the Farms are slow for the first load.

Farm1 takes only 15 seconds whereas my Farm2 takes 90+ seconds to render the same page.

I agree that its normal to take 15 seconds during first load but 90+ seconds!  That doesnt seem right!? Why does Farm2 take so much of time to load?

After I perform an IISRESET, its the first page visit that is terribly slow. But after this first visit to the page it becomes normal.

I copy paste here what I mean by it (taken from the developer dashboard enabled):

```
        BeginRequestHandler (0.18 ms)
        PostAuthenticateRequestHandler (0.10 ms)
        PostResolveRequestCacheHandler (70266.36 ms)
            ExecuteOnChannel:GetProfileProperties (56800.21 ms)
                CreateChannelAsProcess:Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IProfilePropertyService (56203.42 ms)
                    GetProcessSecurityTokenForServiceContext (56196.01 ms)
                    CreateChannelWithIssuedToken (6.68 ms)
                InitializeWcfOperation (0.09 ms)
                ExecuteWcfOperation:http://Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles/GetProfileProperties (76.54 ms)
                    CleanUpWcfOperation (0.02 ms)
            GetWebPartPageContent (4983.56 ms)
                GetFileAndMetaInfo (4974.71 ms)
        Proxy Channel call for Enterprise Metadata Service (1033.40 ms)
        CreateChannelAsProcess:Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.IMetadataWebServiceApplication (23.08 ms)
```

As you can see, the ExecuteOnChannel:GetProfileProperties  is taking 60 seconds. What is it and why does it get called?  Pls advice.

Kind Regards,

Jai

Comment: I have a similar error on a load balanced environment, will post if I find any solution. Please update this thread if you figure this out before me

Comment: Related thread on TechNet: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/82331331-b241-4dde-9917-33f4d9f72a3f/sharepoint-2010-startup-slow?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious